# What does characterize "dirty" folk?

Tags: genre-characteristics, folk

As different to "normal" folk? Is it so because of "[dirty](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/what-does-it-mean-for-a-sound-to-be-dirty)" sounds?
Example

https://youtu.be/_ILe0_DovlU

Comment: Hi and welcome to Music Fans.  This question is on topic for us, but some extra details would help.  Where did you hear the term used?  Can you provide some examples of "dirty folk"?

Answer (score 3):

"Dirty folk" does not seem to be a term in wide or common use.  The ["dirty blues"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_blues), however, is an old and well-established subgenre of the blues.  It is called "dirty" because it has "dirty" words and/or sexual themes.  Based on the link you provided, "dirty folk" is likely the same thing for folk music --folk music with bad language and/or sexual themes.

An alternate interpretation would be, as you suggested, folk music with a "dirty" audio quality, but this would more likely be called "gritty", "lo-fi" or "indie" folk.  (The link is somewhat ambiguous because it compiles songs from four separate genres.)

Either way, there is likely some overlap with "anti-folk" which is a low-fi folk subgenre with contemporary, often explicit language and themes.